# I want to upload a camera video stream to Amazon S3 and download it to an Android phone. I'm completely new to this. How can I do this?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, ip-camera, live555, mpeg-dash

I'm really dumb and new to RTP/SIP. Is there a stack that's recommended for uploading video to the cloud from a camera attached to a microprocessor? What's the difference between all the things I'm seeing - MPEG DASH, Live555, ffmpeg, and so on...?

How does WhatsApp or Dropcam transmit live video?

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a video on it's own is fairly trivial if the video has already been captured you will just need to set your app to have access to the local media store, list the files and then upload using any standard technology e.g. HTTP PUT, HTTP POST, FTP, S3 etc

If you want to process the video first you would be wise to first process it via a library such as ffmpeg which has been compiled for Android e.g. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android

If you want to live stream the video hence your reference to RTP/SIP etc you will need to access the camera. You could start with something like the kickflip SDK as a basis and includes a bundled ffmpeg https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-android-sdk or libstreaming: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming